# Why don't the lists get inserted correctly into my dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

`a` should be `[-1,-1,-1]`, `b` should be `[-1,-1,0]` ... `z` should be `[1,1,0]` and lastly   should be `[1,1,1]`. When `print(i, "is: ", temp)` is run through every loop the correct answer gets shown, but when I print the dictionary after the loop all the values are `[2,-1,-1]`.

```
alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "

alfabetKod = {}


temp = [-1,-1,-1]

for i in alfabet:
    print(i, "is: ", temp)
    alfabetKod.setdefault(i, temp)
    

    if temp[2] == 1:
        temp[2] = -1
        if temp[1] == 1:
            temp[1] = -1
            temp[0] += 1
        else:
            temp[1] += 1
    else:
        temp[2] += 1
    
        
    
print(alfabetKod)
```

Comment: You only have one list, and you keep _changing_ its contents.

Comment: Thats the point, it should change for every loop so that not the same values get added. Is that a problem?

Comment: Evidently it's a problem, because you're here asking about unexpected behaviour. You need _multiple lists_, not just one. Try running it in e.g. https://pythontutor.com/ to see what's happening.

Comment: Oh okay, so i should create 27 empty lists and then assign them the different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing only a reference to the list into your dict, not the current values. Try changing `alfabetKod.setdefault(i, temp)` to `alfabetKod.setdefault(i, temp.copy())` to write the values instead of a reference.

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked, didnt know that python worked that way :o